# Typesetting with Inch Symbols and Sizes in Inches

Tags: typography, units

I'd be much obliged if somebody could tell me how to do the following.

- How does one typeset the symbol for inches in LaTeX? Is it `"`?. Neither Lamport nor Knuth seem to mention it.
- Assuming `\inchcommand` is the command that produces the inch symbol, does one insert a thin space before the command: `1\,\inchcommand`?
- When you write 8.5 x 11 paper size, it is not clear the sizes are in inches. Is there a way to make the unit explicit?

Comment: How about `\newcommand{\inches}{\ensuremath{{}^{\prime\prime}}}` and set it without any space between the numeral and the unit? It looks aesthetically okay to me...

Comment: I would rather have 8.5in x 11in with a thin space between the number and the inch. But please use SI units:) This is also the reason why you cannot find it in `siunitx`, the package focuses on SI units.

Comment: @Yannis Good point about SI units. I should have realised. I'll remove the comment about it.

Comment: Isn't the symbol for inches the straight quote (2"), the other ones (“like these”) for quotations? I have read something like that in a Danish typesetting guide.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In most style books it is recommended that you spell it out fully. If you however insist to typeset it as per the question use as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo,amsmath}
\def\inch#1{#1''}
\def\ft#1{#1'\thinspace}
\begin{document}
    6'\thinspace30''
%or
    \ft2\inch6
\end{document}
```

You can use the same method for typesetting time this way as well. You can create commands to suit. Even better to typeset it straight into SI units and let TeX do the conversion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\def\inch#1{#1''}
\def\ft#1{#1'\thinspace}
\def\inchtomm#1{%
   \FPmul\result{#1}{25.4}
   \FPround{\result}{\result}{2}
   \SI{\result}{\mm}}
\begin{document}
6'\thinspace30''

\ft2\inch6

\(\inchtomm{8.5}\times\inchtomm{11}\)

%or

\(8.5\thinspace\text{in}\times 11\thinspace\text{in}\)
\end{document}
```

If you absolutely need to typeset it in inches, use `8.5~in` or `\mbox{8.5\thinspace in}`. Both are acceptable ways from a typesetting point of view.

**Edit**

Had a look at a few guides. The image is from *Science and Technical Writing, a Manual of Style*, 2nd Edition by Philip Rubens. (Highly recommended)

[image]

The overall consensus in the context you describe is to spell it out in full words. In tables, the inches appear as a heading and the `by` symbol used i.e., `5 x 10`

The abbreviated form in text can take a stop or be left out `in.`; as units in my early Engineering Books always used it as `in` i.e., `lb/in` etc.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I typeset the letter (paper) size? I'm not familiar with the convention.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen See edit.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I don't want to convert to metres. If I convert 8.5 x 11 (in inches x inches) to the equivalent in metre x metre, I am sure nobody will recognise the paper size anymore. I just want to make the unit (inch) explicit. For example, should I write 8.5" x 11", should I write 8.5 x 11 inches, should I write ...?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Better to write 8.5 x 11 inches. Most style guides recommend you spell it out fully. Others will accept 8.5in x 11in.

Comment: Are you sure about the usage of quotes in your answer? The back quote seems out of place here. I'd prefer primes instead of closing quotes, but that's a matter of opinion.

Comment: @egreg It is better to use the right symbol U+2033 (some symbols fonts have them). Good catch with the backquote it should be a prime also. I edited it out.

Comment: Unfortunately, the option `utf8` for `inputenc` doesn't provide a translation for U+2032 and U+2033. There is with `utf8x`: they become `\ensuremath{^{\prime}}` and `\ensuremath{^{\prime\prime}}` respectively. Providing a definition for them, either with `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` or via `\newunicodechar` may help in making an "engine-independent" document.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. Will check it out later and see if I can incorporate it into the code.

Answer (score 11):

Independent of which symbol you actually go with you should make use of [the `siunitx` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx) and use `DeclareSIUnit` to setup the meaning of `\inch`. That way you can use this unit in the same manner as the other SI units, and have all the flexibility that comes with the `siunitx` package.

In the MWE below, I have used `in`, but another alternate is to use `\textquotedbl` (`\inchQ`) as shown in the output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% Needed for \textquotedbl
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = {}]{\inchQ}{\textquotedbl}

\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = {\thinspace}]{\inch}{in}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    \SI{8.5 x 11}{\inch}  & \SI[product-units = single]{8.5 x 11}{\inch}\\
    \SI{8.5 x 11}{\inchQ} & \SI[product-units = single]{8.5 x 11}{\inchQ}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

As others have said, it's generally best to spell out "inches" in full.

However, the correct sign for inches is the **double prime**.  Not right curly quotes, not straight quotes, but the mathematical double prime.

In math mode, prime can be typed with a single apostrophe, so "25 feet, 11 inches" can be abbreviated as:

```
25' 11''
```

Sources:

- Robert Bringhurst's *The Elements of Typographic Style*, page 283
- [a question on English Language & Usage SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32463/is-double-prime-the-correct-symbol-to-use-for-specifying-inches)
- [Wikipedia article on the *prime* symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_%28symbol%29#Designation_of_units)
- [an article on indesignsecrets.com](http://indesignsecrets.com/creating-proper-primes.php)

Answer (score 4):

If you do not want to bother with extra math packages, I would suggest you type the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

$8.5\,'' \times 11\,''$

\end{document}
```

Switching to math-mode will ensure that your quotation marks are actually typeset as inch signs and not as quotes (without messing up your quotes in text-mode, indeed). Lengths such as these should usually be typeset as math anyway (lining numbers, not proportional).

(And I have never seen anything about the thinspace, though it does not seem flawed to me. It may depend on the font you are using, though.)

Edit: Have a look at Bringhurst (p. 169 for instance). The inch marks are clearly heavier at the top than at the bottom. I don't know if inverting them (as Yiannis Lazarides has done) is also acceptable, but I have never seen it. He uses proportional numbers throughout – but I would think both lining and proportional would be correct, depending on the context of course (if there is no other math at all in your document, you might want to go for proportional, otherwise go for lining).

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure if all typographers agree with the comment in the last sentence of your first paragraph. [Hochuli, pages 40] writes that you should actually use the letter `x`, not `\times`. He also uses oldstyle (not lining) proportional figures: 10 x 12 cm (the 1 is clearly proportional). @Book{Hochuli, author = {Hochuli, Jost}, title = {Details in Typography}, year = {2009}, publisher = {Hyphen Press}, isbn = {978-0-907259-34-3},} Bringhurst also uses oldstyle figures (the 9 in 9 1/8 is clearly not lining).

Comment: @MarcvanDongen I disagree with Hochuli about the `x`: the letter and the multiplication symbol are two different objects that should be clearly distinguished. Would you use an ell for the numeral one?

Comment: @egreg He claims that the `\times` is correct in mathematical contexts but too obtrusive in other texts. I had noticed the convention of using an `x` in picture/painting dimensions before.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Yes (as I also mentioned later in my answer). But it probably depends on the context, the type of document and your other typographic choices regarding the typesetting of numbers (which in turn depend on the font, etc.) – because they have opted for this convention, which is fine in their context, does not mean all books should apply it indiscriminately. Bringhurst uses \times (and even if you use proportional numbers, the `x` is still semantically more of a multiplication sign… you don't want serifs there).

Comment: @MarcvanDongen I believe that this recommendation is not endorsed by many authors.

Comment: @egreg Hochuli guy teaches typography, and specialises in microtypography. He wouldn't have written it if there wasn't some truth in it. I don't know what to think, but as I wrote, I had noticed this convention for dimensions of paintings.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Not two typographers agree on everything, except perhaps the fact that typography is not about rigid rules. And that many typographic “conventions” have their origins in commonly made mistakes.

Comment: @ienissei Thanks. I had noticed the different conventions:-)

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I don't think it's appropriate to use the mathmode commands `\prime` and `\prime\prime` (raised to superscript height, of course) to denote the **length** units *foot* and *inch*. Rather, these commands should be reserved for the **angular** units *arc-minute* and *arc-second*.

Hence, I'd advocate the use of `'` and `''` in text mode for feet and inches. If there's a chance you may need these unit designations in math mode, just create the macros

```
\newcommand\foot{\mbox{'}}  % if using amsmath package, use \text rather than \mbox
\newcommand\inch{\mbox{''}} 
\newcommand\feet\foot   % define the plural versions of the macros...
\newcommand\inches\inch
\newcommand\by{\mbox{$\times$}} % for "by", suppress spacing placed around `times`
```

in the preamble. This will let you typeset the dimensions of a standard piece of construction lumber in either math or text mode, viz.,

```
$2\inch \by 4\inches \by 8\feet$ % math mode
2\inch \by 4\inches \by 8\feet   % text mode, using the macros
2''\by4''\by8'                   % text mode, using double and single apostrophes
```

as follows:

[image]