# Straight quotes?

Tags: punctuation

How do I get a straight quote instead of curly quotes? I’m not inside `verb` or `listing` or any other special environments, and I’m not using XeLaTeX or anything—just normal LaTeX. I don’t want to change all quotes, just get the occasional straight quote. For example, I’d like a way to get something like this in the TeX:

```
... some examples of these glyphs are curly quotes (``''),
straight quotes ('"), and angled quotes ($'$$"$) ...
```

to look like this in the output:

```
... some examples of these glyphs are curly quotes (“”),
straight quotes ('"), and angled quotes (′″) ...
```

As I’m using an academic-publisher-provided template that does its own required font setup, I’m extremely wary of changing fonts or font encodings. I think the template uses the `times` package, and the formatting instructions say all fonts must be Type 1.

Comment: I'm asking *why* you'd want to do that to begin with.

Comment: @andrew Most guides recommend that you spell out feet or inches see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46055/typesetting-with-inch-symbols-and-sizes-in-inches

Comment: Edited to clarify that feet and inches was just a poorly-chosen example, I actually want straight quotes.

Comment: You can find `\textquotesingle` also via [http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).

Comment: @YiannisLazarides I would say most guides recommend using metric system instead of feet and inches ;-)

Comment: maybe related: [Is there any other of doing quotes and double quotes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36812/isnt-there-any-other-way-of-doing-double-quotes-in-latex-besides)

Comment: The straight quote is used in displaying computer language text. It is ASCII/Unicode character (`0x27`); one Unicode alias is "apostrophe-quote." Its glyph on the Unicode code chart is vertical and symmetric. It can be found on some typewriters. In my youth I used a typewriter that did not have an exclamation point. Instead, you typed `'` `[backspace]` `.` The Apple II, Atari 400, and Commodore 64 all had straight quotes (see [Damien Guard's article, Typography in 8 bits: System fonts](https://damieng.com/blog/2011/02/20/typography-in-8-bits-system-fonts)). StackExchange has straight quotes.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24417/150618

Answer (score 45):

(*Minor update, April 2022*: loading the `textcomp` package to access the glyph generated by `\textquotesingle` is not necessary if the vintage of your TeX distribution is more recent than 2019.)

You write

> I ... just [want to] get the occasional straight quote.

The typographically correct marks for "feet" and "inches" are not (single or double, resp.) straight quote marks, but *angled* quote marks. These may be produced in "normal LaTeX" via `$'$` and `$''$`, resp.

**Addendum**, prompted by the OP's comment that interest lies only in "straight" (vertical) quotes. In addition to the "single-quote" command `\textquotesingle` (requires loading the `textcomp` package -- if the vintage of your TeX distribution is older than 2020), there's also the `\textquotedbl` macro, which is available as long as a font encoding *other* than the original TeX font encoding (aka `OT1`) is used.

Here, then, is a quick MWE. Note that the text font is TNR (Times New Roman). If your publisher wants to use a font encoding other than `T1` -- which is what I use in the MWE -- that's no problem at all, as long as your publisher's template doesn't impose `OT1`...

```
\documentclass{article}
% access \textquotedbl:
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
% access \textquotesingle:
  \usepackage{textcomp} % not needed for TeX vintages more recent than 2019)   
% load "Times New Roman" text font:
  \usepackage{mathptmx} % (note: the "times" package is obsolete!)

\begin{document}
He exclaimed, \textquotedbl Hello,  
\textquotesingle Stranger\textquotesingle.\textquotedbl
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Second Addendum**, to address a late comment by @FlashSheridan, who claims that

> \textquotesingle (with or without textcomp) produces a curly closing quote, not the straight quote I need for a short C fragment.

This claim simply cannot be correct in general. As `\textquotesingle` is defined in the `textcomp` package but not the LaTeX kernel, `\textquotesingle` *without* `textcomp` *produces an error message, not a curly closing quote.* (Update April 2022: This paragraph is irrelevant if your TeX distribution is more recent than 2019.)

The following screenshots (first for Latin Modern, then for Times Roman) demonstrate conclusively that `\textquotesingle` does produce a straight vertical quote. In contrast, `\textsf{'}` does not produce a straight vertical quote -- unless, of course, some sans-serif font with straight single quote glyphs has been loaded.

[image]

[image]

Finally, the code to produce the preceding screenshots:

```
\documentclass[border=1pt,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}  % for \textquotesingle macro
\usepackage{mathptmx}  % or: lmodern
\begin{document}
Times Roman

\verb+\textquotesingle+: \textquotesingle

\verb+\textsf{'}+: \textsf{'}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Feet and inches was a poorly-chosen example—I should have been clearer that I actually want straight quotes.

Comment: @andrew -- thanks for this clarification. I've provided an addendum to my answer.

Comment: That sentence could as well be a nice example of the advantages of the [`\enquote{}` command](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36812/isnt-there-any-other-way-of-doing-double-quotes-in-latex-besides), provided by the [csquotes package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes).

Comment: @matth -- Good observation. Why don't you provide an answer in which you use the `\enquote` commands with parameters suitably chosen to generate straight (vertical) single and double quote marks?

Comment: @Mico Based on the OPs examples I think `\enquote{}` is not what the OP wants here (even if I consider it a nice solution). An answer using `\enquote{}` could of course help others, but then again there are many examples in the question I linked to.

Comment: \textquotesingle (with or without textcomp) produces a curly closing quote, not the straight quote I need for a short C fragment.

Comment: A more helpful (though imperfect if you look closely) answer:  \textsf{`} from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662037/how-to-write-programming-code-containing-the-character-in-latex

Comment: @FlashSheridan - If the `textcomp` package isn't loaded, `\textquotesingle` produces an error message unless an unusual (and so far unspecified) font package is loaded. Your claim that "\textquotesingle (with or without textcomp) produces a curly closing quote" therefore has no chance of being valid in general.

Comment: This is with a document converted by pandoc, with my only package additions makecell and hanging.  Pandoc does say “% use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments”  (For my own stuff, I use \textsf{'}, but that environment is admittedly pretty weird.)

Comment: @FlashSheridan - I've posted an addendum to demonstrate that `\textquotesingle` indeed produces a straight vertical quote, your claim notwithstanding. If your document doesn't produce this result, there's very likely something important in your document setup that's redefining the meaning of `\textquotesingle`.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it must be something imported by pandoc.  (There doesn’t seem to be a way to attach a screenshot; let me know if you want it.)  Since this was my only use of ', I can get by with \textsf{'}.

Comment: `\textquotesingle` and `\textquotedbl` work (now) without any packages (under xelatex), as well as a bunch of other quote commands: `\quotesinglbase`, `\textquotedblleft` and so on, both under TS1 encoding (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7735/how-to-get-straight-quotation-marks), and TU; except two: `\textquotestraightbase` and `\textquotestraightdblbase`.

Comment: @Cicada - Are you sure about this claim, at least for pdfLaTeX? If I try to compile `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} \textquotesingle \textquotedouble \end{document}` -- note that neither `textcomp` nor `fontenc` are loaded -- on my system (MacTeX2019, all add-ins up to date), I get "Undefined control sequence" messages about `\textquotesingle` and `\textquotedouble`.

Comment: @Mico, quite right: I tested just minutes ago before getting back online: pdflatex generates the error; it's OK in xelatex and lualatex. (I presumed all engines had the same 'core').

Comment: @Cicada - Even though LuaTeX and XeTeX have been (fairly) stable for several years by now and offer significant extra capabilities over pdfTeX, the inescapable fact is that the pdfTeX is still the engine used by the overwhelming majority of TeX&friends users. TeX users are, for one reason or another, quite conservative and slow to change their habits -- at least their typesetting habits. Sigh.

Comment: @Mico, Not enough slots. I can see now why pdflatex has to error out: it loads `cmr10.pfb` by default, which only has 128 slots, none of which is a single quote; `textcomp.sty` pulls it in via TS1 encoding, hence the need for `fontenc` package to manage encodings. Meanwhile, `tuenc.def` defines it as unicode and so xelatex and lualatex need nothing further and merrily go on their way, the system font taking care of things. (It's very cramped, the legacy font world, juggling in and out of 128-element arrays.)

Comment: @Mico, I've discovered `DeclareTextSymbol`!  (as used in tuenc.def) Now I can do as many `\text...` as needed: with `\DeclareTextSymbol{\textipaturneda}     \UnicodeEncodingName{"0250}`, the command `\textipaturneda`  produces ɐ. It's like being an *X*-eater in an *X*  factory, where *X* = 'delicious'.

Comment: Can `textquotesingle` little bit longer ?

Comment: @alper - As the screenshot shown above (and, as I just noticed, posted almost exactly 10 years ago to the day) demonstrates, the length of the glyph produced by `\textquitesingle` depends crucially on font (family) that's is in use. E.g., the glyph is quite a bit longer for the Latin Modern (LM) font family than it is for the Times Roman family that's available if the `mathptmx` package is loaded. Which font family do you employ?

Answer (score 12):

You can use `\textquotesingle` from the `textcomp` package:

```
\usepackage{textcomp}
....
``The lot is 25\textquotesingle wide,'' the realtor said.
```

There is also a `\textquotedbl` for double quotes in the base LaTeX package. `\textquotedbl` needs a `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in the preamble, [which you should be doing anyway](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-should-i-use-usepackaget1fontenc) although it can cause [weird font trouble](http://mjtsai.com/blog/2005/07/29/roman-straight-quotes-in-pdflatex/). It will be fine with `times` though.

Comment: "The weird font trouble" can be easily solved by installing the cm-super fonts (or by switching to the lmodern fonts).

Comment: Unfortunately external factors require that the document must be in times using only Type 1 fonts so I don’t think I can do that :/

Comment: If you use times you won't have the "weird font trouble". Also installing a font package doesn't force to use it in your document. But if your document needs it it will be there.

Answer (score 3):

For `LuaLaTeX` users, this can be done very easily in the package [`luaquotes`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luaquotes)! (Disclaimer: I am the developer of the package)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{luaquotes}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}  
\begin{document}
\dumbquotes
\addfontfeature{RawFeature=+qtbye}
    "I heard John say, 'Hi'. It was nice"
\end{document}
```

[image: ][2]]

Answer (score 1):

```
\char13
```

Pakin writes:

> Outside of verbatim, you can use \char18 and \char13 to get the modified quote characters. (The former is actually a grave accent.)

Scott Pakin, "ASCII and Latin 1 quick reference" in [*The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List*](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Answer (score -2):

If the single quote or your double quote changes automatically try putting them inside textnormal like:
`\textnormal{"Hello"}`