# Modifying `biblatex-trad` options

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

This is based on the solution given in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58152/how-to-emulate-the-traditional-bibtex-styles-plain-abbrv-unsrt-alpha-as-clo).

I'm using [`trad alpha`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-trad), but I don't have year for two papers from the same author:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{chapterref.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{
  shortdesc,
}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{shortdesc}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backref, refsegment=chapter, datamodel=chapterref, 
style=trad-alpha % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69706/38244
]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author    = {Author, A. and Duthor, D.},
  year      = {2001},
  title     = {Alpha},
  shortdesc = {Conference1},
}


@misc{noyear,
    author = {Nuthor, C.},
    title = {New title},
}

@misc{noyear2,
    author = {Nuthor, C},
    title = {More new title},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
  \chapter{First Chapter}
  Some more text \autocite{A01}. More citation \autocite{noyear} and again \autocite{noyear2}


  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Notice that the citation keys are **[Nuta]** and **[Nutb]** (highlighted in yellow):
[image]

What I want is, The index for the same key is to be Arabic numbers (instead of alphabets) with an upper comma before it:

> [Nut'1], [Nut'2]

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{'#1}
```

Or if you prefer a straight quotation mark (see [Straight quotes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52529/35864))

```
\usepackage{textcomp}
\DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{\textquotesingle #1}%
```

Comment: First one is fine for me!