# How to get U+0022 char (plain double quote) in latex?

Tags: unicode

I would like to get this char within general text in latex: `"`

But I only am able to get `“` or `”`

i.e. I would like to include the U+0022 unicode char in my document. But if I do this: `\char"0022` I still get the `\textquotedblright` char. How can i get a simple plaintext double quotes in latex?

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\begin{document}
"abc"

\textquotedbl abc\textquotedbl

\verb+"abc"+

\texttt{"abc"}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With ngerman only the second and third will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

When using ngerman try this one:

```
\texttt{\dq{}example\dq}
```

->  "example"

Otherwise look here: [Straight quotes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52529/straight-quotes)