# How can I have straight quote inside math-mode?

Tags: math-mode, quotation

I have following piece of code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \Upsilon\textquotesingle^{hr}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

its output, where both single-quotes looks kind of italic:

[image]

---

Instead is it possible to have a straight quote, like this one: `Y'`

I have applied following question but seems like it does not work inside `equation`: [Straight quotes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52535/127048)

Comment: normally in math you would use a prime, so  `\Upsilon'`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle did you remember the `^{hr}`? So it might be `^{\prime hr}`?

Comment: @daleif Did you remember that `'` looks ahead for a following `^` and produces `^{\prime hr}` :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle right

Comment: @alper - `\textquotesingle` is a text-mode command. You shouldn't use in math mode. Instead, use eitehr `'` or, equivalently, `^{\prime}`.

Comment: can I wrap `\textquotesingle` inside  `\text{}`? I have tried it but the length of the quote was pretty small  @Mico

Comment: @alper - I'm reluctant to provide advice here since I have no understanding of the math formula you are trying to typeset. It appears that you're averse to using `'` (or, equivalently, `^{\prime`) even though that glyph is much longer than what's produced by either `\textquotesingle` or `\textup{\textquotesingle}`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want the vertical quote, I suggest a macro using `\textup`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\newcommand{\quot}{\textup{\textquotesingle}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \Upsilon\quot^{hr}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you can use
`\Upsilon^{\quot hr}`, which produces

[image]

One more option is to define `\quot` inside a `\raisebox`:

`\newcommand{\quot}{\raisebox{.3ex}{\textup\textquotesingle}{}}`

Then `\Upsilon\quot^{hr}` produces

[image]

Of course, you can raise more or less by changing the `.3ex`.

Comment: Noooooo, try adding `\itshape` before the equation to see why. `\text` is _never_ the answer. Perhaps `\textup` is better.

Comment: @daleif: Fair enough. Edited.

Comment: @daleif: Thanks.

Comment: @SandyG When I tried your solution quote shows up shorter and little bit to the right (I believe something on my code prevents its original position) , when I tried to change `.3ex` it did not made much change : example figure: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/3d0a41a177499a795ab09d0ee83b8563?permalink_comment_id=4139551#gistcomment-4139551

Comment: @alper: That is not the font from your MWE. It's probably not difficult to adjust the spacing but not without knowing the font information.